# Explanation of .net code

Tags: c#

Can someone explain what is happening in the following code:

```
private IList<SomeModel> ImportSomething<T>(IEnumerable<ISomeInterface> someResponse, Func<ISomeInterface, Conversion<T>> converter) => someResponse
    .Select(converter)
    .Where(conversion => conversion.Status == ConversionStatus.Success)
    .Select(conversion => conversion.Object)
    .Cast<SomeModel>()
    .ToList();
```

The code above is called by:

```
ImportSomething(collectionOfThings, _thingConverter.FromXmlResponse)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a generic method whose signature is the following:

```
private IList<SomeModel> ImportSomething<T>(
    IEnumerable<ISomeInterface> someResponse
    , Func<ISomeInterface, Conversion<T>> converter)
```

This method has two arguments. The first one is a sequence of `ISomeInterface` objects. Wherease the second one is a Func which takes as an input an object that implements the interface `ISomeInterface` and returns an object of type `Conversion<T>`. Essentially it is method that convert the input of an object that implements the interface `ISomeInterface` to an object of type `Conversion<T>`.

Then for a given input, which is denoted as `someResponse` some transformations applied.

First, for each item in the sequence `someResponse` the `converter` is applied:

```
someResponse.Select(converter)
```

This way all the `ISomeInterface` objects in this sequence would be converted to objects of type `Conversion<T>`.

Then the items that failed to be converted would be filtered out and a new sequence would be created with the objects that have been converted successfully:

```
Where(conversion => conversion.Status == ConversionStatus.Success)
```

After this a projection is made and from the `Conversion<T>` objects we have we get only the `Object` property:

```
Select(conversion => conversion.Object)
```

Last we cast each item in our sequence to a `SomeModel` object and we request the immediate execution of our query by calling the `ToList` method.

The reult of the executed query would be a `List<SomeModel>` objects.

The above steps can be more specific if you have a concrete example as the one you mentioned:

```
ImportSomething(collectionOfThings, _thingConverter.FromXmlResponse)
```

Now the sequence of objects on which all the above would be applied is the `collectionOfThings` object and the converter that would be used is the `_thingConverter.FromXmlResponse`. It is not needed you specify the `T`, because the compliler can infer it form the the type of `_thingConverter.FromXmlResponse`.

Answer (score 1):

Not what actually happens, but logic idea is same.

```
var result = new List<SomeModel>();

foreach (var response in someResponse)
{
    // Select(converter)
    var conversion = converter(response);

    // Where(conversion => conversion.Status == ConversionStatus.Success)
    if (conversion.Status == ConversionStatus.Success)
    {
        // Select(conversion => conversion.Object)
        var value = conversion.Object;

       // Cast<SomeModel>()
        var model = (SomeModel)value;

        result.Add(model);
    }
}

return result;
```